# functions and the commutative property

Tags: functions, vector-spaces

with regard to vector spaces of functions. How do I know if the commutative property holds for a set of functions. especially if the vector space includes an infinite set.

for instance, for the vector space C(-∞, ∞), which of the following are subspaces?

a) all functions f such that f(1) = 0

b) all nonnegative functions f

c) all differentiable functions

a) I can see why adding a a function of this set to another will also fall into the set, but how can I be certain that for any two functions that intercept at this point, will satisfy x+y = y+x?

b) apparently this one does not satisfy the commutative property, why?

c) and this one does?

Comment: Ok, cool. My textbook seems to run through all 10 axioms for each question which is why I did not simply test for closure. very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test whether these subsets of a vector space are subspaces, the principal property you need is not commutativity, but *closure*.  For $x,y$ in the subset, you need $x+y$ to also be in the subset, and also $ky$ to be in the subset for every scalar $k$.  [you also need the subset to be nonempty]

For (a), if $f,g$ is in the subset, then $f(1)=0=g(1)$.  But now $(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=0+0=0$, so $f+g$ is in the subset.  Also $(kf)(1)=kf(1)=k0=0$, so $kf$ is in the subset.  The identically zero function $f(x)\equiv 0$ is also in the subset, so the answer is "yes".

For (b), the function $f(x)=x^2$ is in the subset, but not every scalar multiple of it is.  For example, $(-2f)(x)=-2x^2$ is not nonnegative for all $x$.

For (c), you need to know that the sum and scalar product of differentiable functions is again differentiable.  You also need that the identically zero function $f(x)\equiv 0$ is differentiable.